# Advice on web directory structure for Mac OS X 10.6 Server

Tags: apache-2.2, wordpress, mac-osx-server, osx-snow-leopard

I'm looking for suggestions on directory structures on where to put the web root on a Mac OS X 10.6 server. Got about 10 sites, most using Wordpress. Is just making a root folder on the drive fine? I've seen some recommendations to use /usr/local as well. Any thoughts are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

my guess would be '/var/www'.

as far as i understand this is the unix/apache default directory for web sites.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the built in tools for managing OS X's web services?  If so, the default location is /Library/WebServer/Documents.  I think the location is arbitrary unless you need to put it on a separate volume for data protection &/or speed.